# Login System details in JSF

Tags: jsf

how to use gmail user,yahoo user like that user their account to login my application which developed in JSF

i want like Openinviter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OpenID](http://openid.net/) for this, like as Stackoverflow does. You can find [here](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#java) a list of all available Java libraries, each pointing to their own homepage which includes more background information, documentation and code samples.